# How to write "ORDER BY NULL" using codeigniter query builder

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to optimize a query and I need to include this clause `ORDER BY NULL`.

I wanted to find out if there is any way to add this using the query builder.

I have tried this: `$this->db->order_by('NULL')` but it does not work. Any help?

Comment: Try taking the quotes out of `NULL`? You're passing in a string instead of the null value.

Comment: @aynber That removes the ORDER BY clause entirely when you do that

Comment: Order by takes a column name. Also, null cannot be sorted by value - it has no value.

Comment: @DFriend in MySQL, order by takes null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: I used the third argument and that was it.

```
$this->db->order_by('NULL', '', false);
```